# Вопрос пунктуации перед союзом «как»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп

*Мы оплатим(,) как только вы закончите работу.*

Нужно ли ставить в данном предложении запятую перед "как"?

Comment: Запятая перед 'как' нужна.

Answer (score 2):

***Мы оплатим, как только вы закончите работу.***

Запятая ставится, так как это сложное предложение, в состав которого входят два простых с основами: ***мы оплатим*** (главное предложение), ***вы закончите*** (придаточное предложение с подчинительным временны́м союзом «как только»).

[**КАК ТОЛЬКО**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_355), *союз*

> Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «как только», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми.
>
> *Председатель подождал, пока подсудимые заняли свои места, и, **как только** Маслова уселась, обратился к секретарю.* Л. Толстой, Воскресение. ***Как только** в начатой вещи появляются люди и **как только** эти люди по воле автора оживают, они тотчас же начинают сопротивляться плану и вступают с ним в борьбу.* К. Паустовский, Золотая роза. ***Как только** прошла гроза, я отправился в слесарную мастерскую...* К. Воробьев, Вот пришел великан.

Answer (score 0):

Если "как" - это что-то, за что платят, то запятую нужно ставить после "как":
Мы оплатим как, только вы закончите работу.
Т.е. по завершении работы над каком работникам будет выплачен гонорар!

Comment: Тогда уж добавьте ещё один "как" перед "только", а то не очень по-русски звучит.

Comment: Бред собач**ач**ий!

Comment: Нет, Александр! Здесь смысл другой! "Как только вы закончите работу" - это одно! А "ТОЛЬКО ВЫ ЗАКОНЧИТЕ РАБОТУ!" - другое. Это как мать сыну говорит: Я куплю тебе пивка, только выучи уроки (она как бы умоляет его). А если как вы предлагаете, то получится обыденно: Я куплю тебе пивка, как только выучишь уроки...

Comment: Тогда поставьте тире – так понятнее будет, потому что глагол "закончите" имеет одинаковую форму в будущем времени и повелительном наклонении, в отличие от "выучи"/"выучишь". :))

Comment: Вы сами поставьте, я не очень поняла, где ставить. Устала...

Comment: Простите, Кет, не хотел вас обидеть, как-то нехорошо получилось. Имел в виду, что запятая после *как* нелепо выглядит, надо перед.

Comment: Да я знаю, что вы тонкий человек! Просто было юморное настроение! Конечно, мой ответ - шуточный! Так что вы всё правильно написали :)

Comment: Браво! Как вы верно всё поняли!)